# How to model the following problem?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Let's say, I have the following tables in MS-SQL Database:

*Please note: This database composition is just fictional, because I'am not allowed to share sensitive business data.*

**Category**

- Id *(int, pk)*
- Name *(varchar(50))*

**Game**

- Id *(int, pk)*
- Name *(varchar(50))*
- CategoryId *(int, fk: Category->Id)*
- etc...

**Participant**

- Id *(int, pk)*
- Name *(varchar(100))*
- etc...

**Composition**

- Id *(int, pk)*
- ParticipantId *(int, fk: Participant->Id)*
- GameId *(int, fk: Game->Id)*
- Date *(date)*
- Time *(time)*

The problem is that, only one Game per Category per Participant is allowed for a given Date and Time.

So for example:

Tim can participate only in one game from one category at a time.

Valid composition:

- Tim -> Football (Ball games) -> 2017/02/02 -> 12:00
- Tim -> DOOM (Video games) -> 2017/02/02 -> 12:00
- Tim -> Football (Ball games) -> 2017/02/02 -> 13:00
- Tim -> DOOM (Video games) -> 2017/02/02 -> 13:00

Invalid composition:

- Tim -> Football (Ball games) -> 2017/02/02 -> 12:00
- Tim -> Baseball (Ball games) -> 2017/02/02 -> 12:00

My first idea was to set a unique index to *Composition* table *ParticipantId + GameId + Date + Time*, but it still allows me to add two or more games from the same Category.

Finally the question is, is it a design problem, or I just have to add a check constraint to maintain data consistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to enforce this is to add `CategoryID` in `Composition`. Then you can add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(ParticipantID, CategoryID, Date, Time)`.

This requires to modify the foreign key to `Game` and to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `Game` (or modify the existing one). The tables that need changes:

```
Game
    Id (int, pk)
    Name (varchar(50))
    CategoryId (int, fk: Category->Id)
    etc...
      UNIQUE (CategoryID, Id)                            -- added

Composition
    Id (int, pk)
    ParticipantId (int, fk: Participant->Id)
    CategoryId (int)                                     -- added
    GameId (int) 
      FK (CategoryId, GameId) -> Game (CategoryId, Id)   -- modified
    Date (date)
    Time (time)
      UNIQUE (ParticipantID, CategoryID, Date, Time)      -- added
```

Comment: To be honest, couple hours ago I found a solution... but till now, I couldn't update my post. Anyway, my solution is almost identical to your answer, except that I modified the Game table PK from *(Id)* to *(Id + CategoryId)*. Otherwise I don't know how could it be FK in other table. I don't think that a UNIQUE constraint is enough for it, but feel free to correct me, if I'm wrong. Thank you!!

Comment: A PK means just unique constraint + not null. (you can have only 1 PK but as many as you like UNIQUE). It would work either way for the FK.

Comment: Also note that the composite FK is needed for the desing to work right.

Answer (score 0):

Your table design is fine.
I would add a trigger on table Composition. Whenever a row is inserted or updated then you have to check if the combination of Category, Participant, Date and Time is unique.
A check constraint will not help in your case.